# CSS selector for a button inside div tag

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a html page like this :

```
<html>
  <div> ....</div>
   <div class="genericclassname" data-test="test1">
     <few more tags>
     <div class="somegenericclass1">
       <div class="somegenericclass2">
          <button class="genericclassname2" data-test="left"> ...</button> 
          <button>......</button>
      </div>
      <div>......</div>
  </div>    
 </html>
```

I have many div tags like this. I can select any div tag by using data-test property, but I need to have CSS selector for button with data-test = 'left'

I can select the div with data-test= test1 using following CSS selector :

```
div[data-test='test1']
```

Can anyone help me with CSS selector for this button inside the div tag?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `div[data-test=test1]>button[data-test=left]`

Comment: I have updated the tags. can you please see if it will still works?

Comment: `div[data-test=test1]>div>button[data-test=left]` we can play this for a while

Comment: sorry to again change the tags. but somehow it's showing me as an invalid jquery selector.

Comment: I am now doing it as div[data-test=test1]>div>div>button[data-test=left] but it's still showing as invalid jquery selector.

Comment: What do you mean "invalid jquery selector"? What version of jQuery are you referring to? Where are you getting that error message from?

Comment: It got resolved. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to prove this works with jQuery no problem:

```js
$('div[data-test=test1]>div>div>button[data-test=left]').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> ....</div>
<div class="genericclassname" data-test="test1">
  <div class="somegenericclass1">
    <div class="somegenericclass2">
      <button class="genericclassname2" data-test="left">this should be red</button>
      <button>......</button>
    </div>
    <div>......</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked with div[data-test='test1']>div>div>button[data-test='left']. I had to enter it in one tool so it might had this syntax and was showing invalid query without having quotes for data-test values. Thank you again I tried many things but this worked.